# Is there a way to "see" an added SD card to a booted computer without rebooting?

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

At the moment, if I add a SD card to my computer while it is already on, I cannot see it when I go to "This PC".

If I reboot the computer, I then see it.

Is there a way to see it without rebooting?

Comment: Sometimes Win10 gets confused and allocates a drive letter which is already in use for networking or is a `subst` target. Check if you can see it in `Disc Management`, and assign or reassign its drive letter if so. You should also check if it appears in `Device Manager` and whether there is an associated icon in the system tray for its removal.

Comment: Disc Management: no sign. Device Manager: no sign. Sys Tray: no sign. Thanks anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: One last thing is to right-click the compute at the top of the `Device Manager` list, and try `Scan for hardware changes` - I doubt that `Add legacy hardware` will do anything for you. It looks like a problem with your in-built card reader (if that's what you're using); if not try the card in a USB reader instead, and try it in different USB ports. Alternatively, resuming after hibernation sometimes sorts out hardware problems.

Comment: How are you *"adding"* this SDcard?  MMC slot or USB adapter?  The MMC has an optional "card detect"  HW feature; it would be required for hot plugging.

Comment: Very good. MMC. Will check the HW feature.

Comment: Cannot find such a feature. It there another name. I have tried all the fixes I can find.

Comment: Sorry if I misled you into thinking there was a Win10 feature to enable.  I was trying to describe an optional HW switch that exists on some MMC/SD sockets, that can be used to detect a card insertion or removal event.  E.G. *"A standard MMC/SD card (push and click type) connector, ,,, is mounted on the ,,, board. It features a push-lock / push-eject mechanism and a card detection switch."*  I've seen this work on Linux single-board computers.   Have you considered using a USB card reader?